# installed navigation bar but not cannot link pages on html

Tags: html, css

I have installed a navigation bar, I have created HTML files for each of the options on the bar (home, news, about and contact) but only the address bar changes. I understand I must add an a) tag but I'm not sure where and why I need to change my code. Also, do I need to duplicate this code for each HTML page? my code is below for my index

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.topnav {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
 }

.topnav a {
  float: left;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
 }

.topnav a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

.topnav a.active {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
}
 </style>
 </head>
 <body>

<div class="topnav">
   <a class="active" href="#home">Home</a>
   <a href="#news">News</a>
   <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
   <a href="#about">About</a>
 </div>

<div style="padding-left:16px">
  <h2>Top Navigation Example</h2>
  <p>Some content..</p>
 </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to duplicate the parts of the HTML that should be displayed on every page. The issue with your navigation is that you are using the `<a>` tag `href` attribute not correctly for what you want to achieve. I assume you have to change the navigation to something like this.

```
<div class="topnav">
   <a class="active" href="index.html">Home</a>
   <a href="news.html">News</a>
   <a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
   <a href="about.html">About</a>
 </div>
```

Basically, you have to modify `href=` and add after the `=` the relative path to your HTML file you want to link to. I suggest reading more about [link tags here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_a.asp) and the [href attribute here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_href.asp). If you put a `#` upfront in your `href` attribute you are linking within the current page to an anchor (a tag with a specific `id`). This also changes the URL in the address bar but doesn't open a HTML file.

Comment: Thank you, i will definitely read up on the two links you posted. Thanks for the help :D

Answer (score 0):

You are linking to anchors in your page (made by adding ```id="youranchor"). If you want to link to other pages, you have to do something like this:

`<a href="/news.html">News</a>`

Answer (score 0):

What you have used in your code is used in single page websites where clicking on link will take you to a different section on the same page.

```
<div class="topnav">
   <a class="active" href="#home">Home</a>
   <a href="#news">News</a>
   <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
   <a href="#about">About</a>
</div>

<div id='home'></div>
<div id='news'></div>
<div id='contact'></div>
<div id='about'></div>
```

Here #home, #news, #contact and #about are nothing but 'id' of divisions on the same html page.

If you want your anchor tags to open a different page on clicks then you need to provide the links to your html pages, including their folder structure. Like,

```
<div class="topnav">
   <a class="active" href="home.htm">Home</a>
   <a href="news.htm">News</a>
   <a href="contact.htm">Contact</a>
   <a href="misc/about.htm">About</a>
 </div>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you so much, this really helped and you are brilliant at explaining.

Comment: Happy to help. :)